# Java atmosphere max message limit

Tags: java, atmosphere

Is there a way to increase the message size in atmosphere framework? I'm doing to do file uploads of 2 to 3MB files via WebSocket. And I see the below reason,

> Websocket closed, reason: The decoded text message was too big for the
>   output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages
>   atmosphere.js:3221 Websocket closed, wasClean: true

Atmosphere should handle frame buffering internally itself?

Comment: Split message and send it by pieces

Answer (score 0):

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.maxTextMessageSize</param-name>
            <param-value>10485760</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Set the max value to be more than 8192 bytes, for me it was 10MB as a max limit.

-Fahad